# Placing two divs at same horizontal level

Tags: html, css

I need to put two div elements at the same horizontal level. Doing the way I have done makes  the second one get displayed under the first.
I want to place them in a way that they cross over each other while transition.

Edit 1- [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ht6M9/3/) when the button is pressed to swap their classes, divs move up and down.

```
#aaidi,#aaidi3 {
-webkit-transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out;
transition: margin-left 1s ease-in-out;
}
.left {
margin-left: 45%;
border: 1px solid green ;
width: 20px;
height: 4px;
background: #FF0000;
} // similar for right with margin-left:55%
......
        <tr>
           <td colspan=3>
              <div id="aaidi" class="left">
              </div>
              <div id="aaidi3" class="right">
              </div>
           </td>
        </tr> // after this there is a button pressing whom changes the class of both divs.
```

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, but its not working when I put the button there. See comments in your answer.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ht6M9/3/) when the button is pressed to swap their classes, divs move up and down.

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve this using the `float` property:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.container {
        margin: 15px;   
    }
    div.left, div.right {
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;    
    }
    div.left {
        background-color:orange;    
    }
    div.right {
        background-color: yellow;    
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csLwu/1/) for a demonstration.  Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: It's dropping to the next line because the combined margin equal 100%, which forces the element to drop to the next line. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ht6M9/2/

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ht6M9/3/) when the button is pressed to swap their classes, divs move up and down.

Comment: Try adding the property (display:inline-block) to the style

Answer (score 2):

Use a `span`, or you can set the style to `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you would like to float the divs

```
.float-left{
  float:left;
}

 <div id="aaidi" class="float-left left"></div>
 <div id="aaidi3" class="float-left right"></div>
```

If the right div is still being viewed as a 'block' element then it will take up the entire row. Both elements need to be floated, or specific widths need to be set.

Answer (score 1):

see fiddle for code and demo

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ht6M9/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ht6M9/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Just float all divs left if you require them to be side by side.

Depending on contents of div, you may need to assign a width to each class too.